# Software Engineering Interview Memory allocation

Tags: java, c, memory

I was working on this problem I found online for a SDE internship. I was wondering if anyone could help solve this problem because I am quite loss. I am trying to figure out a smart way to insert the allocated memory address and the starting address into a hashmap. Would there be a specific hashcode I would have to use? Preferably in java. Thanks in advance!

Assume that you have 2^32 bytes of memory. When a program asks to allocate memory, a 4kb chunk of memory gets allocated. It can be allocated at any position (e.g. 0, 57, 8192). Now assume we have a function called lookup(), which, when fed an arbitrary address, (1) returns the value of the starting address of the chunk encompassing the requested address if it was allocated, or (2) returns a value indicating false if no block was allocated. Lookup must work IN CONSTANT TIME. To help clarify the functionality, here is some example expected behavior:

```
Allocate(1) /* allocates bytes 1-4096 */
Allocate(4099) /* allocates bytes 4099-8194 */
Lookup(123) /* returns 1 */
Lookup(4096) /* returns 1 */
Lookup(4098) /* returns -1 or false */
Lookup(6042) /* returns 4099 */
Lookup(8198) /* returns -1 or false */
```

Comment: I am trying to figure out a smart way to insert the allocated memory address and the starting address into a hashmap.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @JisooHan You should probably include your comment in the question, as it specifies what and how you want to do it and thus makes answering easier

Comment: Okay, sorry I just added it!

Comment: "I am trying to figure out a smart way", well, figure it out!

Comment: @UniCell well I have been working on the problem for quite a while now and could not answer it so I'm asking if anyone here has any ideas.

Comment: Maybe they're asking for a clever solution or maybe it's a trick question to check if you know what constant time means. You have a constant number of bytes and a constant maximum number of allocations. Even if you just keep a long list of allocations, lookup will be constant time (unless you REALLY mess it up!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Mikkel K, the question is not very well formed. I am assuming that they want you to supply a solution that keeps the time constant reasonably small.
Here is my suggestion:

Allocate:

Hash on the 20 most significant bits of the address.

If a block spans 2 hash numbers (which is true for all blocks that don't align on an even 4096 bytes), then add the allocation record twice, both to the list for hash X and the list for hash X+1.

Lookup:

Hash on the 20 most significant bits of the address.
Get the list of allocation records associated with the hash value. The list will contain 0, 1 or 2 allocation records.

Compare the starting byte of the alloction records in the returned list with the address in the parameter and determine which allocation record it belongs to (if any).